# Passing an index between tableviews using prepareForSegue not working

Tags: xcode, uitableview, segue

**What I'm trying to do:**

When a category is tapped in *tableViewController 1* the corresponding information is displayed in *tableViewController 2*

**How I am trying to do this:**

I have a property `var index = 0` in tableViewController 1. `index` is equal to the `indexpath.row`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    index = indexPath.row
    print("Button tapped\(index)")
}
```

I have a `prepareForSegue` that passes `index` to tableViewController 2. tableViewController 2 also has a property named `var index = 0`. I am making `subjectDetailTableViewController.index` (tableViewController 2's index) = tableViewController 1's `index`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let subjectDetailTableViewController = segue.destination as? SubjectDetailsTableViewController {
        // make the indexes equal between view controllers
        subjectDetailTableViewController.index = index
    }
}
```

Next, the `viewWillAppear` method of tableViewController2 uses the new value of `index` to determine how to load the cells

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Determine the subject tapped, then correspond with the correct information

    if index == 0 {
        loadAnatomy()
    } else
        if index == 1 {
            loadFormulas()
        } else
            if index == 2 {
                loadHemodynamics()
            } else
                if index == 3 {
                    loadProcedures()
                } else
                    if index == 4 {
                        loadRadiology()
    }
}
```

This way if the user taps the cell called ANATOMY (which is `indexPath.row` number 0) in tableViewController1 the `loadAnatomy()` method will populate tableViewController 2's cells with ANATOMY information

T**he problem:**

It does not always work. It seems to be one step behind. If I tap another category i.e. FORMULAS (which is `indexPath.row` number 1) it will load Anatomy. Then if I go back to tableViewController 1 and press FORMULAS for a second time it works correctly.

I thought I had the if statement in the wrong spot, so I moved it from the `viewDidLoad` method of tableViewController 2 to the `viewWillAppear` method. But that did not fix this.

What am I missing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess you did connected the segue from the `UITableViewCell` to `tableViewController2`. Instead remove it, and do it from `tableViewController1` to `tableViewController2`, and in didSelectRow, call yourself `self.performSegue()`

Comment: So I changed the segue from the tblVCell -> tblViewCon 2 to tblViewCon 1 -> tblViewCon 2. The ID is: `SListToSDetails`. I then updated `didSelectRow` to: `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {br/self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SListToSDetails", sender: self)<br/>index = indexPath.row<br/>print("Button tapped\(index)")
    }` It didn't work :( I still kept my original `prepare(for segue:` method above. I notice that the `index` updates itself when I go from tblViewCon 2 back to tblViewCon 1 which is a step too late.  @Larme

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to figure out how to do line breaks in the code. I'm not used to formats in the comments. You might see unnecessary <br/> (because I thought that was a line break lol) @Larme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my override function from:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if let subjectDetailTableViewController = segue.destination as? SubjectDetailsTableViewController {
    // make the indexes equal between view controllers
    subjectDetailTableViewController.index = index
}
```

}

To:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

    let index = indexPath?.row

    if let subjectDetailTableViewController = segue.destination as? SubjectDetailsTableViewController {
        // make the indexes equal between view controllers
        subjectDetailTableViewController.index = index!
    }

    if let mainViewController = segue.destination as? MainViewController {
        // Do not animate launch when seguing back to Main Menu
        mainViewController.initialLaunch = false
    }

}
```